# Order by not working as expected when using ASC

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a filter function (Formula1) that returns a range and it works fine.

But when I use this inside query function (Formula2) then appears following problem: If I leave filter condition empty (See B1) then order by asc not works.
[image]

If I select DESC then again it appears ok.
[image]

If I select a value in B1 then again it appears ok, Please help in solving issue with ASC when B1 is empty.

This is the concerned [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18jhQxN0nGPakLhvxJR4SDqocMqzpkzpi8Qlj8dMuN1k/edit#gid=737237920).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the updated formula in your sheet which adds the `not null` condition to populate rows w/out blanks.

`=index(query({split("Client,Location,Remark,Paid,Pending,Age,Date,Boolean1,Boolean2,Boolean3",",");filter(input!A2:J,input!A2:A=if(B1<>"",B1,input!A2:A))},"Select "&join(", ","Col"&index(sequence(1,9)))&" Where "&join(" is not null OR ","Col"&index(sequence(1,9)))&" is not null"&" order by "&B2&" "&B3))`